# How to know the datatype returned when hardcoding values in sql

Tags: sql, sybase

Is there a way to know what datatype is returned by a query with literals in it?

For instance, I am pretty sure `select 1` returns an int, but how do I -know- it?

I can do this `select 1 + "2"` which will respond with `implicit conversion from 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed` which tells me that `1` must be an `INT`. But is there a better way?

EDIT: My specific usecase is the following:
I write/modify a stored procedure that hard codes a certain value. Maybe I am replacing a field that used to be grabbed from a table or maybe I am writing a new procedure that has literals.

The java that executes this stored proc will fail if I use the wrong ResultSet.getX().
Without going through the overhead of testing in java, it would be nice if there was an easy way for me to tell what a certain collumn's type is.

Comment: Is `CAST`ing and using that datatype in java not valid?

Comment: There is apparently a way to do this because SQurrieL supports it.

Answer (score 0):

it depends for example with PHP and MySql you can retrieve fields name and type.
can you provide more information?

Comment: This isn't an answer, and what kind of information do you need? I hoping to find a way to do it using SQL only. Obviously PHP must have a way to figure out what the type is. How does it do that?

Comment: @user606723 The answer to your question is basically no, but we understand there is a specific problem you're trying to solve and there is probably an answer to that problem if you tell us more about the 'problem' rather than the approach you think will solve it.

Comment: information like what kind of language are you using, implementing! SQL is too generic, there are different versions.

Comment: @Gabs, the question is tagged with `Sybase`

Answer (score 0):

When you are modifying the stored procedure surely you what kind of data it is at that point in time, right?  If so, you could store that info in a lookup table so you can get at it later.

Outside of that, the only thing I can think of is if you dynamically created a table with the result and then queried syscolumns but that's probably a bit overkill.

Comment: I have no problem running it. Basically, I want to be able to verify after running it what type a certain column is.

Comment: Well, there has to be a way to do it.. How else would any API, etc have any idea what it is...

Comment: @user606723 Are you not able to use ResultSet.getObject()?  And then you can use java to find the actual type of the object.  Or are you just asking how you can avoid doing that?  And if you are just trying to avoid it... why?  Do you think you will get a significant performance gain?  (FYI, I'm just throwing thoughts out... I'm still pondering how you might do this directly in SQL and will answer that if I think of something).

Comment: (a) There is no reason to do that in the production java, because I already know what the datatype should be. The code will error out if it's not the correct datatype, and that's perfectly fine. (b) So, if I happen to modify a stored procedure and use a literal, I need to make sure I didn't change the type of that literal. The only way to currently do that is to unit test the java code and make sure it still works as expected. But if I can do some sort of inital test to double check the datatype on the sql side, I can do this check before hand...

Comment: Also, using the getObject method only tells me the Java datetype, not the SQL datatype.

Comment: @user606723 Ah, I admit I'm less familiar with Java than I am with .net.  In .net I can infer the sql data type from the .net data type.

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile since I used Sybase, but there once were system tables where datatypes can be extracted from; sysobjects, syscolumns and systypes. For example, to return the data types for all columns in table Accounts:

```
select c.name, t.name from systypes t join syscolumns c on t.xusertype=c.xusertype where id = object_id('Accounts')
```

Comment: You can find the datatype in a table using `sp_help`, but how do I do this for just a query?

Comment: This example is a query. What programming language will you use to process this task?